# Creating an XML btach file with SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, batch-file

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT top 100 
         Student.LearnRefNumber AS StudentRefNumber,
         case 
            when PrevlearnRefNumber is null then ('') 
            when PrevlearnRefNumber is not null then PrevlearnRefNumber 
         end AS PrevlearnRefNumber,
         case 
            when PrevUKPRN is null then '' 
            when PrevUKPRN is not null then cast(PrevUKPRN as varchar) 
         end AS PrevUKPRN,
         cast(ULN as varchar) AS ULN,
         FamilyName AS FamilyName,
         GivenNames AS GivenNames,
         cast(DateOfBirth as varchar) AS DateOfBirth,
         cast(Ethnicity as varchar) AS Ethnicity,
         Sex AS Sex,
         NINumber AS NINumber,
         cast(PriorAttain as varchar) AS PriorAttain, 
         cast(FFRRHProb as varchar) AS FFRRHProb,
         case 
             when ALSCost is null then '' 
             when ALSCost is not null then cast(ALSCost as varchar)
         end AS ALSCost,
         cast(PLHours as varchar) AS PLHours,
         case 
            when PERPours is null then '' 
            when PERPHours is not null then cast(PERPHours as varchar) 
         end AS PERPHours,
         cast(Aest as varchar) AS Aest,
         cast(TocType as varchar) AS TocType,
         case 
            when AddLine1 is null then '' 
            when AddLine1 is not null then AddLine1 
         end AS AddLine1,
         case 
            when AddLine2 is null then '' 
            when AddLine2 is not null then AddLine2 
         end AS AddLine2, 
         case 
            when AddLine3 is null then '' 
            when AddLine3 is not null then AddLine3 
         end AS AddLine3,
         case when AddLine4 is null then '' when AddLine4 is not null then AddLine4 end AS AddLine4,
         case when PostCode is null then '' when PostCode is not null then PostCode end AS  PostCode,
         case when Email is null then '' when Email is not null then Email end AS Email,
         case when TelNumber is null then '' when TelNumber is not null then TelNumber end AS TelNumber, 
         CPType AS CPType,
         cast(CPCode as varchar) AS CPCode,
         FFRRTYPE AS FFRRTYPE,
         CAST(FFRRCode AS VARCHAR) AS FFRRCode,
         StudentTamType AS StudentTamType,
         CAST(StudentTamCode AS VARCHAR) AS StudentTamCode   
      FROM 
         Student 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         StudentContact ON Student.StudentRefNumber = StudentContact.StudentRefNumber
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         StudentPreference ON Student.StudentRefNumber = StudentPreference.StudentRefNumber
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         HealthIssues ON Student.StudentRefNumber = HealthIssue.StudentRefNumber
      LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         StudentTAM ON Student.StudentRefNumber = StudentTAM.StudentRefNumber
      ORDER BY 
         Student.StudentRefNumber
      FOR
         XML PATH ('Student'), TYPE  
)
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT ('xxxxxxx')
GO
```

I have changed table names and columns so if there is a miss match please ignore.

I basically need to create a xml batch file that contains the data you see in the code.

Everything under the column `Aest` needs to be under other child relationships of the XML path `Student` which is the first thing that needs to be fixed.

The next thing is that everything needs to be linked to `StudentRefNumber` which it is currently because it is all under one from clause. But by doing that I have not separated the data into child relationships.

The other problem is that the way the data is stored is more appropriate to xml structure rather than relational database structure. Therefore there is a one to many relationship between all the other tables to student. This causes a lot of data to come out separated.

What I would like is a student contact xml path which is a Parent path of the student with all the different student contact info that will be one to many so there will be more than one set for every student path.

Comment: Can you add an example of your current output and what you would expect as output. Can you explain what a batch-file has to do with your question?

Comment: Your question needs to be improved to get help from others...

Comment: These lines `case when AddLine1 is null then '' when AddLine1 is not null then AddLine1 end AS AddLine1,` could be simplified into `ISNULL(AddLine1, '')` - if the value is not `NULL`, return the `AddLine1` value, otherwise the `''`. Would be **much simpler**, much more approachable ....

Comment: Also: when using `CAST` with a `VARCHAR`, I would recommend to **always** explicitly define a **length** for the `VARCHAR`: `cast(PERPHours as VARCHAR(20))` (or whatever makes sense in your case). Otherwise, you could suddenly have nasty surprises..... (there is a default length used when none is specified - do you happen to know what that default length is??)